# rails: login singup(registration) and admin forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, authentication, admin, registration

I am new to ruby on rails
I want a rails application it contain login form, registration form, order page and admin form,user order a product it update on admin page.
example: user have 3 products 1.laptop 2. phone 3.speakers, if user ordered phone, it must display on admin page like x user order phone.
please help me, I am beginner, please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is just a small brief .I can't write complete code over here.

You can use Devise gem for login & registration.

For adding roles to the particular user , use cancan gem.

Then , create scaffold for Product.

Create the view for corresponding pages.

Insert the products.

Create Order model & controller , create association with product & so on...